# e.preventDefault(); not working with https

Tags: jquery, css, node.js, https

I'm using bluehost to host a webpage being served through express in node.js

```
var app = express();
app.listen(80);
```

You can navigate to the page using either port 80 for HTTP or with port 443 for https. Essentially, I just manually type HTTP or https before the page URL to control this.

I have a form within an ejs page with jquery waiting for the form submit, when it is submitted I use e.preventDefault() to stop the page from reloading and then use ajax to send this form data to the node server. The ejs page then has some CSS transitions that look nice while I want for the node server to respond and for the success function to run. This works locally as well as when the page is being hosted with HTTP. If I connect with https the form data doesn't actually go through to the server (it console.log's some info on the server side when the form is submitted) and the page just refreshes. What could be the problem that's causing this different behavior?

Any help is appreciated

Edit:

This is the client code for the form that should not allow the page to refresh, but when connected on https will refresh and not post.

```
<form id="sendmessageform" name="sendmessageform">
  <input type="text" name="logcustomername" placeholder="Customer Name" id="logcustomername" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="tel" name="logcustomernumber"  placeholder="Customer Phone Number" id="logcustomernumber" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="logstorename"  placeholder="Store Name" id="logstorename" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<script>
$('#sendmessageform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/submit',
        type: 'post',
        data:$('#sendmessageform').serialize(),
        success:function(data){
          console.log(data)
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And the server side for this route

```
app.post('/submit',
  function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body)

    var temp = new Object();
    temp["statustype"] = "pass";
    temp["content"] = "message contents.";
    
    // return a temporary json object to the client
    res.send(temp);
  });
```

Edit2:

I've tried changing out the e.preventDefault() for e.stopImmediatePropagation(), the page no longer refreshes when the submit button is clicked even on https. My only issue now is, the form is submitted and the server console.logs the form data when I'm connected on HTTP, but nothing happens when I'm connected on https. It's as if the ajax doesn't even attempt to post the form.

Comment: Please show the particular client code that you're having a problem with and ideally show us what the live URL is so that we can actually try/debug things.  From your limited description, it's unlikely we will know what to suggest.  Also, please show the `app.post()` handler for your server-side code.  If the client-side page reloads, it sounds like you're not successfully preventing the default page action when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a simple mistake. I tried adding an alert("Test") box to the top of the jquery function and that wasn't popping up when the button was clicked, which was telling me it wasn't an issue with the form itself but that jquery itself wasn't trying to run. Looking at my headers, I was referencing the jquery source using HTTP not https, so when I connected with https my browser gave an error that this wasn't allowed. Changing the source URL to https:// fixed the issue entirely.